# NullPointerException when iterating null ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, nullpointerexception

I have following code running in 2 different environments. First environment is development environment in Eclipse with Java 7 using Java 6 compliance to run my webapp. And other is my development server running Java 6. Following code throws NullPointerException on development server, but not on my development environment. Can someone explain why this is happening?

```
List<String> list = null;
for(String s : list)
{
// do something
}
```

Comment: After all what is the use of this statement `List<String> list = null;`? It's completely useless.

Comment: @Lion it is just example, in my code it is of course not like that, I just know that in my code in that point variable is null.

Comment: What happens when you try it by adding some values to your `List` (by not keeping `null`) on both the environments. Does it work on both of them?

Comment: Sorry, it wasn't null, but something is different in these enviroments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will always throw an exception.  What is more likely is that something is failing in one environment and the value is null and not failing in another environment where it is not null.

Answer (score 3):

The code, as written, will throw an exception every time.  Make sure the code is compiling correctly in your development environment.  If it is running successfully, it is running a different version of the code (probably an older version of the class that doesn't throw a NullPointerException).

Answer (score 0):

Are you kidding? This will explode every time guaranteed.

If it "isn't exploding when run somewhere else", I guarantee you are not running this code.